# Eclipse shows blank screen after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

I've purchased a Netbook for Android app development. I use Eclipse for this. It used to work great. Yesterday, I upgraded to 12.04 and everything works great, but Eclipse doesn't start anymore. It just shows a blank screen, which I can't click away.

[image]

I'm not really an extremely technical guy, But I really need this to work. And yes I've removed and re-installed eclipse.

Comment: Are you using portable eclipse or eclipse from repository?  There are lots of weird issues with portable eclipse.  I personally use eclipse from repository and it works great.

Comment: I've got the same problem one two computers. With one I've used the Ubuntu Software Center and on the other I've downloaded the .deb file. Same problem :(

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen/had-to-fix this issue.  You could try installing the PDE as well.  I've got `eclipse, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-pde, eclipse-platform, eclipse-platform-data, eclipse-rcp`.  I got them with eclipse and eclipse-pde.  Everything else was dependencies.

Comment: I thought it's kinda weird the question wasn't asked yet. Thanks though! I'll try installing it from a different source. Edit - Thanks! Checking it out right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the problem - should anyone recognize the above screenshot, the problem lies with dropbox sync across 11.10 and 12.04. It's unrelated to download locations.

Opening up a blank workspace and copying files there solves the problem.